# How to give vintage art more modern look?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, filter

How can I give a vintage art more modern look? Remove yellowish color from white? Is there some kind of preset or recommended settings( brightness, saturation etc) ?

From this: [image: from this]

To this:[image: to this]

Comment: The original is so warm and beautiful. The artist did a wonderful job at conveying mood not merely setting. Seems a shame to try and change it.. like recoloring the Mona Lisa... The recoloring, to me, is merely cold and emotionless. You've essentially taken the painting from a warm summer/spring day, to cold winter/fall afternoon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be argued that there is a yellow colour cast on the image due to it's age, although I quite like it the way it is, and I would agree with Scott's comment, that it gives a pleasant warm hue to the painting, however if you really do want to remove the yellow colour cast, it is possible. But something a little more subtle would be better. In the example edit, the colours are just washed out, and a beautiful warm summer day has been turned into a miserable grey overcast day.

One of the easiest/simplest ways is to do *Image > Auto color*. Here's the result.

[image]

If you want a little more control, an alternative method is to use the Adobe Camera RAW filter. Under the Basic settings, you can simply move the temperature slider a little to the blue end of the spectrum - don't go too far though, and perhaps add a little more vibrance and clarity to the image. Here's an example of that.

[image]

For a more subtle result you could also bring back some of the warmth to the scene in the foreground by adding a mask to the edited layer, over the top of the original.

[image]

Comment: .... " could be argued " .... yup I'd argue it `:)` The original still has clear very white streaks in the building... i.e. no yellow-cast. I think the warm coloring was intentional. But nice job killing it `:)`.

Comment: @Scott - yeah, I prefer it without the edit too, and it may indeed be the intended colours, but the OP did ask how to do it. ;)